# Both Lan and wifi not working

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, kernel, lan

I installed ubuntu 12.04 on my recently purchased Toshiba satellite but both Wired and wireless are not working.
I tried Fedora 19 64 bit but it works perfect.
How can I use ubuntu then.
Is there any method you can forward.
I also heard about clonzila .
Can I make an installed copy of ubuntu from any other sytems(which is having LAN).
Please help me geeks...

Comment: What was the output of `rfkill list`?

Comment: Before we proceed, let's identify your wireless and ethernet devices. Please edit yourr question to add the result of this terminal command: lspci -nn | grep -e 0200 -e 0280

Answer (score 0):

Type "`sudo rfkill list all`" in terminal. If it shows that you have soft/hard blocked LAN

and wifi, you can

correct it by executing "`sudo rfkill unblock all`".